# Telegram gif dimensions are invalid

Tags: telegram-bot, gif, image-resizing, dimensions

GIF dimensions are invalid. Must be 320x180, 640x360 or 960x540 pixels.
I tried to use a resize app and it still didn't work. I have even used a regular gif from my keyboard and it doesn't work. When I send a gif it also says please send a gif as if it didn't recognize it as a real gif.
It's even sent this reply response  Now upload a demo GIF or send /empty to skip this step.